# max-height transition　don't work？

Tags: css, transition

1. I want to use pure CSS make collape panel like Bootstrap 
   [bootstrap collapse panel](http://v3.bootcss.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion)
2. but max-height transition don't work ,Why?
3. how to toggle the panel if I checked,I want to the panel collapse when  I double click

```css
  * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .content {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #ccc;
    margin:40px auto;
    border:1px solid #eee;
  }
  label{
   padding:10px;
  }
  .content>div{
   width:100%;
   transition: all ease 1s;
  }
  p{
    word-break: break-word;
    height: 0%;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height ease 1s;
  }
  input[type=radio]{
   transition: all ease 1s;
   -webkit-appearance:none;
  }

  label:hover+input+p{
 max-height: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div>
      <label for="demo1">demo1</label>
      <input type="radio" name='demo' id='demo1'>
      <p>dsfjhbklweji;dfsfjhbk lwedsfjhbklweji;df sfjhbklweji;dfovjji;dfovj</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="demo2">demo2</label>
      <input type="radio" name='demo' id='demo2'>
      <p>ewrsds fjhbk lweji;dfsfjh bklwedsfjhbkl weji;dfs fjhb klweji;df ovj ji  ;dfokj</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="demo3">demo3</label>
      <input type="radio" name='demo' id='demo3'>
      <p>sdjkassfjhbklweji;dfsfjhbklwedsfjhbklweji;dfsfjhbklweji;dfovjji;dfodlnjk</p>
    </div>
```

[link in JSfidle](https://jsfiddle.net/liuestc/1wfz5btp/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On every time `radio:checked`, you can give `transition` to `p tag` for `opacity` and `height`, as below,

> (plus + selector) - selects all independent elements that are placed after input element here, like here p is placed after input.
>
> The max-height property is used to set the maximum height of an
>   element. It prevents the used value of the height property from
>   becoming larger than the value specified for max-height.

```css
.content{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  margin:auto;
}
p{
  height:0px;
  opacity:0;
  word-break:break-word;
  transition:all 0.6s ease;
}
input[type="radio"]{
  -webkit-appearance:none;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + p{
  height:50px;
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div>
      <label for="demo1">demo1</label>
      <input type="radio" name='demo' id='demo1'>
      <p>dsfjhbklweji;dfsfjhbk lwedsfjhbklweji;df sfjhbklweji;dfovjji;dfovj</p>
    </div>    
    <div>
      <label for="demo2">demo2</label>
      <input type="radio" name='demo' id='demo2'>
      <p>ewrsds fjhbk lweji;dfsfjh bklwedsfjhbkl weji;dfs fjhb klweji;df ovj ji  ;dfokj</p>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <label for="demo3">demo3</label>
      <input type="radio" name='demo' id='demo3'>  <p>sdjkassfjhbklweji;dfsfjhbklwedsfjhbklweji;dfsfjhbklweji;dfovjji;dfodlnjk</p>
    </div>
```